# How to customize an installer's UI

Tags: visual-studio, installation

I am building an installer for my windows app and have done this through a setup/installer project in visual studio.

I was wondering how to customize he UI of the finish dialog box? I want to add a couple of check-boxes and launch an app after the user closes the finish box.

Is there a way to do this in Visual studio itself or does it require any other tools? If other tools are required then are any of them free?

Thanks
Kapil

Comment: Don't know about the visual studio tools, but i've used NSIS in the past, and I'm sure this allows for such customizations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual studio deployment projects give you some standard templated dialog boxes.

If none of these templates meet your requirements, you can create your own custom UI and use an [installer clas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.aspx)s to control the workflow.

To launch an app at end of the installation you would again probably have to override a method in your installer class.

If all this seems like hard work, it's certainly worth looking at something like INNO Setup or WIX.

Answer (score 1):

[Inno Setup](http://www.istool.org/) is free and has the ability to [run things](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_runsection.htm) when the install is complete.

Comment: Thanks guys! Will look into these tools