# Beautifying Visual studio installer 's screen

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

Creating a installer from visual studio setup project ,creates a setup (.exe or .msi) in the defaults screen style. 
Is there a possibility to beautify this?
I mean i  want to create a setup project which gives a installer (.exe or .msi) with good looking UI , like an zune installer or similar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to customize an installer's UI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913844/how-to-customize-an-installers-ui)

Comment: My question is different . I want to change how the UI looks

Comment: It's rather limited, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439/visual-studio-setup-project-custom-dialog. Note that the setup project is not supported anymore as from VS2010. You might want to think to use WiX or Installshield.